# Implement IDispatch::Invoke to be called by a WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to do what they explain on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041%28VS.85%29.aspx#Controlling_Download_and_Execution) article in the `Controlling Download and Execution` section. I understand the `Web Browser Control` in that context is not .NET's `WebBrowser`.

What I'm trying to do is to gain control over what the `WebBrowser` control downloads. I've been searching for this a lot and always en up in the `csEXWB`, which has a huge code that I just cannot decipher.

What I've done so far is inherit .NET's `WebBrowser`, make my inherited class com visible by using the `[ComVisible(true)]` attribute, add this method to my class (taken from csEXWB):

```
    [DispId(HTMLDispIDs.DISPID_AMBIENT_DLCONTROL)]
    public int Idispatch_AmbiantDlControl_Invoke_Handler()
    {
        return (int)m_DLCtlFlags;
    }
```

And then call this line of code, where `Browser` is an instance of my derived class:

```
IfacesEnumsStructsClasses.IOleControl oleControl = Browser.ActiveXInstance as IfacesEnumsStructsClasses.IOleControl;
oleControl.OnAmbientPropertyChange(IfacesEnumsStructsClasses.HTMLDispIDs.DISPID_AMBIENT_DLCONTROL);
```

So what I'm hoping is that the `oleControl` will call my `Idispatch_AmbiantDlControl_Invoke_Handler` method, which it doesn't. I don't know how, and this is probably what my code is missing, is the `oleControl` supposed to know on which object to call my `Idispatch_AmbiantDlControl_Invoke_Handler` method.

What the article I linked above says is `it will call your IDispatch::Invoke`. What does it mean by `your`. How do I tell `oleControl` which object is my `IDispatch`. Hope I'm making any sense.

Comment: You are not close, customizing the host is required.  An internal class named WebBrowserSite in the case of WebBrowser.  Overriding the IDispatch implementation is the hard problem, it is implemented by the CLR for managed code.  Hard to see how you could make this work without native code.

Comment: Well, csEXWB is written in C# AFAIK. Do you know any place where I could get started on how to override the IDispatch implementation?

Comment: The class System.Windows.Forms.AmbientProperties is sealed. Time to abandon the wrapper like csEXWB did.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a customized WebBrowser that allows you to change the DLCONTROL flags.

This is an example code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private MyWebBrowser _webBrowser;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _webBrowser = new MyWebBrowser();
        _webBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        Controls.Add(_webBrowser);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _webBrowser.DownloadControlFlags = (int)WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags.DOWNLOADONLY;
        _webBrowser.Navigate("http://mysamplewebsite");
    }
}
```

And the customized WebBrowser code:

```
public class MyWebBrowser : WebBrowser
{
    private const int DISPID_AMBIENT_DLCONTROL = -5512;
    private int _downloadControlFlags;

    // we want our site class, not the default one
    protected override WebBrowserSiteBase CreateWebBrowserSiteBase()
    {
        return new MyWebBrowserSite(this);
    }

    [DispId(DISPID_AMBIENT_DLCONTROL)]
    public int DownloadControlFlags
    {
        get
        {
            return _downloadControlFlags;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_downloadControlFlags == value)
                return;

            _downloadControlFlags = value;
            IOleControl ctl = (IOleControl)ActiveXInstance;
            ctl.OnAmbientPropertyChange(DISPID_AMBIENT_DLCONTROL);
        }
    }

    protected class MyWebBrowserSite : WebBrowserSite, IReflect
    {
        private Dictionary<int, PropertyInfo> _dispidCache;
        private MyWebBrowser _host;

        public MyWebBrowserSite(MyWebBrowser host)
            : base(host)
        {
            _host = host;
        }

        object IReflect.InvokeMember(string name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, object target, object[] args, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, string[] namedParameters)
        {
            object ret = null;
            // Check direct IDispatch call using a dispid (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de3dhzwy.aspx)
            const string dispidToken = "[DISPID=";
            if (name.StartsWith(dispidToken))
            {
                int dispid = int.Parse(name.Substring(dispidToken.Length, name.Length - dispidToken.Length - 1));
                if (_dispidCache == null)
                {
                    // WebBrowser has many properties, so we build a dispid cache on it
                    _dispidCache = new Dictionary<int, PropertyInfo>();
                    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in _host.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
                    {
                        if ((!pi.CanRead) || (pi.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0))
                            continue;

                        object[] atts = pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DispIdAttribute), true);
                        if ((atts != null) && (atts.Length > 0))
                        {
                            DispIdAttribute da = (DispIdAttribute)atts[0];
                            _dispidCache[da.Value] = pi;
                        }
                    }
                }

                PropertyInfo property;
                if (_dispidCache.TryGetValue(dispid, out property))
                {
                    ret = property.GetValue(_host, null);
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }

        FieldInfo[] IReflect.GetFields(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
        {
            return GetType().GetFields(bindingAttr);
        }

        MethodInfo[] IReflect.GetMethods(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
        {
            return GetType().GetMethods(bindingAttr);
        }

        PropertyInfo[] IReflect.GetProperties(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
        {
            return GetType().GetProperties(bindingAttr);
        }

        FieldInfo IReflect.GetField(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        MemberInfo[] IReflect.GetMember(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        MemberInfo[] IReflect.GetMembers(BindingFlags bindingAttr)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        MethodInfo IReflect.GetMethod(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        MethodInfo IReflect.GetMethod(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        PropertyInfo IReflect.GetProperty(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        PropertyInfo IReflect.GetProperty(string name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        Type IReflect.UnderlyingSystemType
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
    }

    [ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("B196B288-BAB4-101A-B69C-00AA00341D07")]
    internal interface IOleControl
    {
        void Reserved0();
        void Reserved1();
        void OnAmbientPropertyChange(int dispID);
        void Reserved2();
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum WebBrowserDownloadControlFlags: uint
{
    DLIMAGES                          = 0x00000010,
    VIDEOS                            = 0x00000020,
    BGSOUNDS                          = 0x00000040,
    NO_SCRIPTS                        = 0x00000080,
    NO_JAVA                           = 0x00000100,
    NO_RUNACTIVEXCTLS                 = 0x00000200,
    NO_DLACTIVEXCTLS                  = 0x00000400,
    DOWNLOADONLY                      = 0x00000800,
    NO_FRAMEDOWNLOAD                  = 0x00001000,
    RESYNCHRONIZE                     = 0x00002000,
    PRAGMA_NO_CACHE                   = 0x00004000,
    NO_BEHAVIORS                      = 0x00008000,
    NO_METACHARSET                    = 0x00010000,
    URL_ENCODING_DISABLE_UTF8         = 0x00020000,
    URL_ENCODING_ENABLE_UTF8          = 0x00040000,
    NOFRAMES                          = 0x00080000,
    FORCEOFFLINE                      = 0x10000000,
    NO_CLIENTPULL                     = 0x20000000,
    SILENT                            = 0x40000000,
    OFFLINEIFNOTCONNECTED             = 0x80000000,
    OFFLINE                           = OFFLINEIFNOTCONNECTED,
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This was actually a lot easier than I expected. I still need to look at this code a little closer but I tested it and it worked :).