# Reset Webbrowser control to update settings

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, registry, browser, webbrowser-control

I want to use C# with a webbrowser control to switch between the Show pictures option of IE, without needing to restart my application.

My current solution

```
//THE REG FILE:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"Display Inline Images"="yes"
```

The reg file is then executed from my c# project.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process regeditProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/s imagesON.reg");
regeditProcess2.WaitForExit();
```

**the code changes the "show images" setting in Internet explorer to true, and loads all images.**

However the reg file only works once. Once the webbrowser is created the custom settings of IE is loaded into it and any new settings in IE don't update into the webbrowser control. Instead the webbrowser control has to be disposed and recreated for any new settings in IE to take effect.

so, my question, how can i change the settings in IE and load these new settings into the webbrowser control of my running application, without the need of a restart?

**6 Months Later... Still Waiting for a answer here guys :/**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implement IDispatch::Invoke to be called by a WebBrowser control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608550/implement-idispatchinvoke-to-be-called-by-a-webbrowser-control)

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 I have tried this solution, while i think its a great piece of code it is still filled with bugs. Honestly It feels like a overkill for a concept so simple.